# Dozer map a List inside a Map

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I'm using Dozer to Map from one object to another. I know Dozer can do a recursive mapping, but maybe i'm putting too much pressure on Dozer :p I want to map from class A to B

```
class A {
  private Map<String, List<ObjectA>> myMap;
  // getters and setter for myMap
}

class B{
  private Map<String, List<ObjectB>> myMap;
  // getters and setter for myMap
}
```

When I map from A to B I get an instance of B, but inside the Map I got a List of ObjectA. To be clear, I get an instance of this (imaginary) object:

```
class B{
  Map<String, List<ObjectA>> myMap;
}
```

How can I make dozer to perform this mapping correctly?

Note: ObjectA and ObjectB have the same properties (and int and a String).

Comment: Do you have a dozer mapping xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

You could specified [hint](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html):

```
<field>
    <a>A</a>
    <b>B</b>
    <a-hint>ObjectA</a-hint>
    <b-hint>ObjectB</b-hint>
</field>
```